# MVC5 Web Application not looking properly when accessed on intranet after deployment

Tags: css, c#-4.0, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5

I deployed a MVC5 Web Application on the server (IIS7). Site is looking properly when I try to open it from the Server's IE10, but when I try to access the site from another machine's IE10 in the newtwork, the whole site got distorted (seems like some CSS issue).

Same Issue is happening when I deployed it on my local machine. It worked perfectly when I access it from my machine IE10, but got distorted again when I open it from different machine in the network.

However site is perfectly working on chrome in both scenario.

Is there is something to be done with IIS?

Comment: Does adding the site to the Compatibility View Settings help? Does it work on IE11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the following code on my page.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10.0" />
```

Now working fine.

Thanks @lonian316, I got this idea from you that this might be the issue.